# How do I create a proxy object that forwards method calls in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

I'm trying to use selenium to run tests; seems like there isn't a good way to run the same set of unit tests on multiple browsers.

I read this post about running tests in parallel:
http://slmoloch.blogspot.com/2009/12/design-of-selenium-tests-for-aspnet_19.html

However, I'm using the visual studio unit testing framework.

I can create a proxy class like this:

```
public class SeleniumProxy {
    private List<DefaultSelenium> targets;
    public SeleniumProxy() {
        targets = new List<DefaultSelenium>();
        targets.Add(new DefaultSelenium(... "firefox"...));
        targets.Add(new DefaultSelenium(... "iexplore"...));
    }
    public void Open(String url) {
        foreach (var i in targets) {
            i.Open(url);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

My question is this? How can I do it without having to rewrite the entire class as a proxy?

I thought maybe passing a lamda in to map arguments, or passing by a function that takes the name of the method to invoke, but these all seem like pretty lame ideas.

What I really want is to add a member like:

```
public class SeleniumProxy {
    public dynamic proxy;
    ....
}
```

And invoke this like:

```
var selenium = getProxy();
selenium.proxy.Open("...");
```

Does c# allow this kind of syntax for dynamic objects?

Or some kind of meta-handler for classes that lets them catch no-such-method exceptions and handle them manually?

Basically:
How can I create a proxy object that dynamically invokes methods on an internal member of the class?

(Edit: perhaps... using reflection on the DefaultSelenium object and creating function stubs on the dynamic proxy object for each entry..?)

Comment: I'd look again into Selenium Grid if I were you, it's pretty advanced. IE Selenium testing in my experience takes 5 - 10x as long as FF, so if you try to run the tests in parallel your way, your FF tests will also take forever.

Comment: Doesn't really matter if it takes longer; you have to wait for IE anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're attempting, I think you can extend [DynamicObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) to achieve this.

```
class Proxy : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
{
    public Proxy(object someWrappedObject) { ... }

    public override bool TryInvokeMember(System.Dynamic.InvokeMemberBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
      // Do whatever, binder.Name will be the called method name
    }
}
```

`//Do whatever...` would become some code that pokes at some other object's internal members (via reflection, presumably) using `binder.Name` as part of the lookup process.

There are `TryGetMember` and `TryGetIndex` methods to override if you need to wrap up anything fancier that simple method invokes.

You will have to cast instances of `Proxy` to `dynamic` after construction to make arbitrary calls, just like when dealing with [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage inheritance and have your tests defined in an abstract base class with a factory method to create your selenium instance, then inherit this for each type of browser you want to model. The tests will then be run for each inherited class with the appropriate browser. Using NUnit as an example:

```
public abstract class AbstractTests
{
    protected abstract DefaultSelenium CreateSelenium();

    [Test]
    public void TestSomethingA()
    {
        DefaulSelenium selenium = CreateSelenium();

        //Do some testing with selenium.
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class IETests : AbstractTests
{
    protected override DefaultSelenium CreateSelenium()
    {
        return new DefaultSelenium("iexplore");
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class FirefoxTests : AbstractTests
{
    protected override DefaultSelenium CreateSelenium()
    {
        return new DefaultSelenium("firefox");
    }
}
```